# Нужна ли запятая перед сравнением?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот

> Мягок, как вата

Запятая ставится? Можно ли "как вата" считать оттенком значения (очень-очень мягок) и не ставить запятую?

Розенталь пишет о присутствии оттенка значения, но ведь не обязательно образа действия — может ли повлиять на постановку запятой оттенок меры и степени?

Лопатин же говорит конкретно об оттенке образа действия, при наличии которого оборот не выделяется запятыми.

Наверное, в данном случае прав Лопатин, ведь сравнения, выделяемые запятыми, достаточно часто подразумевают оттенок меры и степени, согласны?

Comment: Где в вашем примере вообще действие? (Вы пишете: «образ действия»...)

Comment: В данном примере обсуждается оттенок меры и степени, а не образа действия. В вопросе это написано.

Comment: Я, быстро взглянув, не смог это понять. Может, стоит подыскать другую, более жесткую формулировку? (Я вовсе не настаиваю!)

Comment: Я бы очень хотел увидеть конкретное мнсто у Розенталя, где он такое пишет, что "не обязательно". Поока не вижу ни малейших мотивов в пользу отказа от запятой.

Comment: Розенталь пишет, что обороты выделяются запятыми, если, кроме уподобления, оттенков значения не несут. А выделяются, если в обороте на первый план выступает обстоятельственное значение (чаще всего образа действия). ЧАЩЕ всего, но не сказано всегда, в то время как у Розенталя говориться ТОЛЬКО о значении образа действия.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше и понятнее, чем [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147), я вряд ли скажу.

> Вопрос о пунктуации при сравнительных оборотах, в частности при сравнениях идиоматического (фразеологического) характера, не может решаться в отрыве от характера самих оборотов (сравнения общеязыкового типа или художественные сравнения, иногда индивидуально-авторские), состава устойчивых сочетаний, как он представлен в толковых и фразеологических словарях русского языка, и т. д.

Мягок, как вата (мягкий, как вата) — в отрыве от контекста это обычный сравнительный оборот, не входящий ни в один перечень устойчивых сочетаний. Стоит отметить, что сравнение "как вата" встречается нечасто (можно посмотреть в [НКРЯ](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&lex1=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&parent1=0&startyear=1862&lex2=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0&max2=1&text=lexgramm&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&level1=0&level2=0&endyear=1882&mode=main&env=alpha&min2=1&nodia=1&parent2=0&p=0)), причем практически во всех случаях оно выделяется запятыми.
Есть и без обособления, правда, к нашему вопросу не относящиеся:
*Думать по-настоящему я, конечно, не мог ― голова была как ватой набита...* (братья Стругацкие); *Хлеб тут как вата, его и резать трудно, он весь сжимается* (А. Эфрос).

[Вата](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0&all=x) — слово многозначное (медицинская, сладкая, строительная); вата — субстанция не всегда мягкая (например, в плотном рулоне) и не всегда белая.
Главной характеристикой обычной ваты является все-таки не мягкость, а гигроскопичность, все остальное — сравнительные обороты ("как" — в значении "подобно"):
*море ― просто море, бескрайнее и глухое, как вата;

мгла ― изношенная, мутная и прозрачная, как вата между окнами;

туман, плотный, как вата;

румяные, легкие, как вата, пышки.*

Думаю, что запятую ставить надо.

Мы знали, что русаки уже вышли на озимь и **мягкими, как вата, лапками** неслышно переступают по седой от инея зелени...  [А. А. Ливеровский. Журавлиная родина. Рассказы охотника (1966)]

Сегодня утром – 1°, ветрено, ясно, кое-где бродят по небу, **как вата, белые мягкие облака**. [М. М. Пришвин. Дневники (1923)]

Сверху падали на дорогу, сшибленные ветром с макушек, пушистые и **мягкие, как вата, хлопья снега**, как будто кто-то сидел там наверху и швырялся ими. [С. П. Подъячев. Мытарства (1903)]

Металлические порошки Парацельса сделали, однако, свое дело, они создали чуткость и боязнь жизни в этом хрупком теле, до которого жизнь смела касаться только **руками тети Платоши, мягкими, как вата.** [И. Ф. Анненский. Книга отражений (1906)]

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится обязательно, так как **сравнительный оборот *как вата*** сформировался из придаточного сравнительного *как мягка вата*:

Ср.: ***Мягок, как мягка вата.***

[Придаточные сравнительные](https://rusq.ru/?p=6334)  Придаточные сравнительные часто бывают неполными предложениями.
*Широкие тени ходят по равнине, как облака по небу* (Чехов) – опущено сказуемое *ходят*  ...Если в сравнительной конструкции нет членов предложения, зависящих от сказуемого, то **она превращается в сравнительный оборот**.

*Пили бабушкины наливки, жёлтую, как золото, тёмную, как дёготь, и зелёную* (М. Горький).

Да, можно спросить так: ***мягок (как? в какой мере, степени?), как вата.*** Но запятую всё равно нужно поставить.

Ср.: *Поёт (как? каким образом?) как соловей* *(можно заменить - поёт соловьём*) - запятая не ставится, значение образа действия.

Answer (score 0):

Если подлежащее (мягок) по смыслу тесно связано со сказуемым (вата), то запятая не нужна. Обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не имеет законченного смысла без сравнительного оборота.
Допускается лишь тире (или вообще ничего).

Например:
«Мягкий как облако»,  «Школа — как испытание», «Одни как изумруд, другие как коралл» (Крылов).

https://mel.fm/pravopisaniye/4276358-miracle + Розенталь.